# Is there a way I can redesign radio buttons

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWONA.png)

Is there a way I can redesign radio buttons in android studio to look like the ones in the image? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Lev M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10302746/lev-m) said, we can custom the radioButton in a lot of ways like:

If you add a @drawable archive instead of @color you can change the form.

Example:

1º First create a new file XML in the res/drawable.
2º Write a name and in the "Root element" you should write "shape", so we can create a background and change the shape.Something like this;

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="800dp"></corners>
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"></solid>
</shape>
```

> the "android:radius" means that the edges will be round the number varies,
> And the color means th color of the background.

After setting the XML file you can just put in the background of the radiobutton

```
android:background="@drawable/name_of_the_file_in_xml"
```

that's it